# USA Patent Office

Tags: wo2018177447a1

In reference to the patent: [WO2018177447A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2018177447A1)

Did the applicant apply for patent in USA Patent?

Answer (score 1):

The application has US as designated state. Priority date for the application is 31.03.2017. Hence, probability of this application entering US in National Phase after completion of two years from priority date as 371 application still persists even though it has not entered US as yet.
May check [WIPO](https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/detail.jsf?docId=WO2018177447&redirectedID=true) for National Phase status.

Answer (score 0):

The cited document is an application, not a patent. It may or may not ever get granted. That said, I followed the link to Espacenet and clicked on the [INPADOC patent family link](https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/inpadocPatentFamily?CC=WO&NR=2018177447A1&KC=A1&FT=D&ND=&date=20181004&DB=&locale=). There does not seem to be a USA equivalent.